# Dart - Converting num to double

Tags: flutter, dart, double

Using a Flutter package `FlutterRatingBarIndicator`, I need to use a `double` to determine a x/5 rating. Using another package, `flutter_google_places` to be specific, I get the `num` value `f.rating`.

With `f.rating`, I should be able to convert from `num` to `double` using something like `f.rating.toDouble()` but this is returning `null`.

I'm not sure why it's returning `null` as `f.rating.toString()` returns a non-null value such as 3.5

Is there any special casting I need to apply before a `num` can be used as a `double` value?

Thanks

**Edit; How I get `f.rating`:**

Using `flutter_google_places` I receive `rating` as a `num` value from `result` :

```
  void getNearbyPlaces(LatLng center) async {
    final location = Location(lat, lng);
    final result = await _places.searchNearbyWithRadius(location, 2500, type: 'restaurant');

    setState(() {
      if (result.status == "OK") {
        this.places = result.results;
      }
      print(result.status);
      print(places.toString());
    });
  }
```

This later appears as `places.map` :

```
  final placesWidget = places.map((f) {}).toList();
```

Finally this is used in a `flutter_rating_bar` :

```
  FlutterRatingBarIndicator(
    rating: f.rating,
    itemCount: 5,
    itemSize: 15.0,
    emptyColor: Colors.amber.withAlpha(100),
    itemPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.5, bottom: 6),
  ),
```

Comment: What is `f.rating.runtimeType`?   Can you show code?

Comment: `f.rating.runtimeType` returns a `double`

Comment: Your edited question still doesn't show that you're observing the same instance of `f.rating` when you check its `runtimeType` and where passing it generates a `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'` runtime error. (Also, how do you know that that error comes from `f.rating`?) You also are not showing your real code since `places.map((f) {}.toList();` isn't syntactically valid. Really you need to distill your problem into [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (Doing so might help you identify the problem on your own too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best way around this error, but as far as I've learned a `num` should be supported by `double` specifying parameters. I can't put a pin in the cause of this error as I didn't write/don't totally understand the `google_maps_flutter` package.

The solution I'll be using looks as follows...

```
double drating = 0.0;

final placesWidget = places.map((f) {
   ...
   drating = f.rating.toDouble();
   ...
}).toList();
```

I can then use `drating` as such...

```
FlutterRatingBarIndicator(
   rating: drating,
   itemCount: 5,
   itemSize: 15.0,
   emptyColor: Colors.amber.withAlpha(100),
   itemPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.5, bottom: 6),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

num datatype in dart can store double or integers values,

you don't have to convert it to double!!

Comment: When just using `f.rating`, which is accepted by my IDE, I get the error `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'`

Comment: @Jake Show your code.  You're clearly not talking about the same instance of `f.rating` if `f.rating.runtimeType` is reported as `double`.